# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow using NAudio

Tags: c#-4.0, naudio, lame

While I am trying to convert mp3 to pcm format using DirectX Media Objects(using DmoMp3FrameDecompressor method), I am getting an error "arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" in NAudio. Since there is no support for ACM on 64 bit windows server 2012, I have opted directx media object. Is there any way to overcome this issue.

```
NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader reader = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(ms, wf => new NAudio.FileFormats.Mp3.DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wf));  //  AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(wf))
NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 channelStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(reader);
```

Comment: DmoMp3FrameDecompressor converts MP3 to PCM, not the other way round, so I'm not really sure what you're doing here

Comment: Hi @Mark, You are right I have edited the question. Actually when i am converting it to pcm, the overflow exception as occurred. I want to generate a wave image for the mp3 audio.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the exception you can show? Also, SampleChannel would be better than WaveChannel32 if you can use it.

Comment: I don't have stack trace but, exception is thrown while reading mp3 file i.e., at first line

Comment: does this happen on all MP3 files, or just one in particular?

Comment: I have tested it with mp3 files which worked fine with acmmp3framedecompressor.